# I cannot send pdf attachment with my phpmailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

I am having an attachment problem with my php mailer. All the informations (emails, names, pdf_link etc) are correct and I can receive the email but there is no pdf in the attachment.

Could you please check my codes and tell my what my mistake is, I hope you can help me.

```
//mailing starts

  $mail = new PHPMailer();

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Timeout = 20;
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
  //Set the hostname of the mail server
  $mail->Host = 'my-host-information';

  $mail->Port = 465;//587
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';//tls
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = "myemail@mywebsite.com";
  
  $mail->Password = "****";
  //Set who the message is to be sent from
  $mail->setFrom('myemail@mywebsite.com', 'Name here');
  $mail->addAddress($member_email, '');
  $mail->AddAttachment($pdf_link, $name = $image_name, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');

        $message_it = 'Grazie per il tuo interesse. La tua fattura proforma è stata predisposta e la trovi in allegato. Puoi visualizzarlo sul nostro sistema .<br><br>Cordiali Saluti,<br>My Company';

        $message_en = 'Thanks for your interest. Your proforma invoice has been prepared and you can find it attached. You can view it on our system. <br> <br> Best Regards, <br> My Company ';

        $combined_name_it = 'Caro ' .$member_name.' '. $member_company;
        $combined_email = $email;
        $combined_message_it = $message_it;

        $combined_name_en = 'Dear ' .$member_name.' '. $member_company;
        $combined_email = $email;
        $combined_message_en = $message_en;

  if($email_lang == 'it'){
  $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->Subject = 'La tua proforma è pronta ';         // Email subject
      $mail->Body    = "$combined_name_it,$combined_email<br /><br />$combine_message_it";              // Mail Content
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
  }else{
    $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Your proforma is ready.';         
        $mail->Body    = "$combined_name_en<br />$combined_email<br /><br />$combined_message_en";  
      $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
  }


  $result = $mail->send();

  if($result){
    $session = \Config\Services::session();
    $session->setFlashdata('success', 'Proforma updated');
    return redirect()->to($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }else{
      $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
      $data['title'] = 'Proforma Update';
      echo view('admin/assets/header', $data);
      return redirect()->to($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
      }


  //mailing ends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After solving the issue, I can say that the problem was PhpMailer expected to see the folder part of the url, not the base one. When I included base_url() which includes http:// mywebsites.com etc part, it kept sending the email without the attachment. But, when I replaced it with the folder part, let's say "uploads/invoices/invoice-1.pdf" it worked.

Thanks @Synchro

Comment: PHPMailer’s `addAttachment` function deliberately does not support using URLs for file locations. PHPMailer actively avoids being an HTTP client. The function, as documented, expects a local file path, not a URL.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what language you're used to, but this is weird PHP:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($pdf_link, $name = $image_name, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

Try rewriting that as:

```
$mail->addAttachment($pdf_link, $image_name, 'base64', 'application/pdf');
```

Next, you're not checking the return value of that call, so you don't know if it's been successful, so do that:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment($pdf_link, $image_name, 'base64', 'application/pdf')) {
    echo 'Attachment failed';
}
```

If it is indeed failing, you need to figure out why. The usual reasons are:

- The file doesn't exist
- The path to the file is incorrect
- You don't have read permission
- The file has the wrong ownership

You need to check which of those it is.

Overall, you have almost no error checking or exception handling in your code, so if something goes wrong, it will just break and you won't know why. Take a look at the examples provided with PHPMailer, and make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: Well, first of all thanks. I changed my line with yours and have also added the if (!$mail->addAttachment ..) part but nothing seems wrong. I still receive the email but no attachment. The file exists (I can see it in my folder), the path is correct (I pasted it within body and got the link), the permission is 644..

Comment: I also used with try - catch but no. I receive no error.

Comment: If you want exceptions, you have to enable them by passing `true` to the constructor - please refer to the docs and examples. Enable debug output with `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` so you can see what's actually being sent to your server.

Comment: Well, when I debug the thing that draws my attention is:
Could not access file: my-folder-address-1-proforma.pdf (it indeed exists there) 
and
2021-02-26 18:20:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-srv12.my-server-company.net ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Fri, date-hour etc 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.

Does 220 mean my hosting provider does not let me send it with an attachment ?

Comment: That's what debug output is for! If the file exists in the right place, make sure you're using the correct **absolute** path to it, and that the permissions are correct. Ignore the message from the server, it's just a "welcome" banner, not an error message. 220 is just the successful response code to a new SMTP connection.

Comment: Well, when I copy that url and past it on my browser I can see the file there. Also, even though I hard code it instead of my $pdf_link variable within addAttachment brackets, I still have the same error. I feel baffled actually

Comment: Allright! I solved the problem. Even though my file url was correct, the thing PhpMailer expected to see was the folder part of that url. Not the base one.

Comment: This means that my second suggestion was correct: your file path was incorrect; A URL is not a file path, and you should not be using external HTTP requests to load local resources anyway as it’s massively inefficient and error prone.